# In CRm Dynamics 2013 File Upload and Read file to create records

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an HTML Web Resource in CRM Dynamics which basically uploads a file , I need to now read this file in CRM and create records from the file I uploaded, this is a CSV file. I do not want to use the Import Wizard as the data has to be validated first before being uploaded into CRM. Any ideas on how I can do this sort of integration? I am using CRM 2013 On-Premisis. Is this possible using javascript or what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What can be suggested in your case is to integrate and read your data in your CRM Dynamics 2013 database with tooling that will allow you to Extract Transform and Load (ETL). By doing this you shouldn't have to write Javascript code. And the ETL should allow to connect directly to CRM Dynamics 2013 through configurable connectors.

Comment: Hi Talend Data, are you suggesting creating records directly in the CRM SQL database, I had thought of that but it is not supported by Microsoft. Do you perhaps know how to accomplish this using my question above as an approach.

Comment: The main suggestion would be to use tooling that will let you or other users perform extract, transform and load tasks directly in the database. You can check if CRM Dynamics has connectors with some of the major ETLs available and not have to go through the handwritten Javascript code. When you mention the non-support by Microsoft, is it only the record creation in the CRM SQL database?